# How to selcect all elements that are between a given y on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select all elements in CSS that are between a given y relative to the screen. For example, all elements that are between 30% and 70% of the screen. Like in the picture where the element between the given y values is expanded.
And would preferably make this a CSS selector.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such CSS selectors. You should use JavaScript for it.

And the most efficient way to use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)